Problem Zooming When many objects are in the scene
I've been having this issue on and off for a while. When the scene has many objects in it, blender doesn't want to zoom in and out any more. It first resists zooming by slowing down, and then it wont let me zoom in any more at all. Typically I navigate using the scroll wheel and shift middle click to pan. Any advice?
